# Passing a function down multiple children components in React using ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6, flow-router

I have a `LayoutComponent`, `PageComponent`, and `SingleComponent`.

When my user clicks a button, I want to display a message to the user on a `NewPageComponent` that my application routes to using Meteor's `FlowRouter`.

To do this, I am storing the message in `LayoutComponent`'s state, and then passing this message and a `handlerMethod` down as props to the `SingleComponent` via `PageComponent`, which is a stateless functional component.

I am not having any luck passing the `handlerMethod` down properly to the `SingleComponent` in order to set the message state on `LayoutComponent`.

I know this is a simple syntax issue, but could someone help me find my error?

LayoutComponent:

```
export default class LayoutComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      message: null
    };

    this.handlerMethod = this.handlerMethod.bind(this);
  }

  handlerMethod(message) {
    this.setState({ message: message });
  }

  render() {
    // the PageComponent is actually passed via FlowRouter in this.props.content, so it needs to be cloned to add props
    let contentWithProps = React.cloneElement(this.props.content, { message: this.state.message, handlerMethod: ((message) => this.handlerMethod) });
     return (
       <div>{contentWithProps}</div>
     );
  }
}
```

PageComponent:

```
const PageComponent = ({ message, handlerMethod }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SingleComponent message={message} handlerMethod={(message) => handlerMethod} />
    </ div>
  );
}
```

Component:

```
export default class SingleComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
    };
    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do some more stuff...
    this.props.handlerMethod("You pressed the button!");
    FlowRouter.go("newPage");
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>button</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't actually calling your `handlerMethod` in the code you posted. So this:

```
handlerMethod: ((message) => this.handlerMethod)
```

Should be either:

```
handlerMethod: ((message) => this.handlerMethod(message))
```

Or more simply:

```
handlerMethod: this.handlerMethod
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you're passing a function that will return `this.handlerMethod` instead of call it:

```
handlerMethod: ((message) => this.handlerMethod) // this returns the handlerMethod function, doesn't call it
```

Should be

```
handlerMethod: ((message) => this.handlerMethod(message))
```

You can also pass it directly:

```
handlerMethod: this.handlerMethod
```

The reason passing it directly works is because you're binding the context of `handlerMethod` inside the constructor for `LayoutComponent`, meaning `this` inside `handlerMethod` will be fixed to `LayoutComponent` (*see Note bellow*)

Here's a short example:

Layout Component

```
export default class LayoutComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    // ...
    this.handlerMethod = this.handlerMethod.bind(this); // handler is bound
  }

  handlerMethod(message) {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    let contentWithProps = React.cloneElement(
      this.props.content, { 
        message: this.state.message, 
        handlerMethod: this.handlerMethod // pass the handler directly
      }
    );

    return <div>{contentWithProps}</div>;
  }
}
```

Page Component

```
// pass the handlerMethod directly
const PageComponent = ({ message, handlerMethod }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SingleComponent message={message} handlerMethod={handlerMethod} />
    </ div>
  );
}
```

Single Component

```
export default class SingleComponent extends Component {

  // ...

  handleButtonClick(event) {
    // ...
    this.props.handlerMethod("You pressed the button!"); // call the passed method here
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

*Note*: Technically, you could override bound `this` by calling `new this.handlerMethod` but this isn't happening so you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to pass the method down, you do it like this:

```
const PageComponent = ({ message, handlerMethod }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SingleComponent message={message} handlerMethod={handlerMethod} />
    </ div>
  );
}
```